# Grab all users from Database that meet two conditions

Tags: php, sql, yii

I am trying to get all users who are type `usertype 1` or `usertype 3`.

I think I can do it using a join, but I would like something without join.

Here is what I am trying:

```
$users = User::model()->findAllBySql("SELECT * FROM user WHERE (usertype = 3 and usertype = 1)");
```

I am using Yii but it should be the same SQL principle.

---

> User(id, username, usertype, name);

`usertype` is either 1, 2, or 3.

Comment: Perhaps you want `or`, or perhaps `in`.  You should edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CActiveRecord [`findAll()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#findAll-detail) method in this way:

```
$users = User::model()->findAll(array('condition'=>'usertype = 3 OR usertype = 2'));
```

Comment: Would `findAll()` be faster than the solution I used on my answer?

Comment: I think there is no deference in speed. But `findAll()` is more common and more easy to use. Also **you don't need to use flat sql query and leave it to ORM to doing it for you.**

Comment: Although my answer works, I think yours is better! Therefore I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get familiar with the SQL WHERE clause

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

specifically as @Gordon has pointed out, the "IN" section

***ALTERNATIVELY***

If the ask is to find a user who is BOTH type 2 & 3 then you could try

```
select distinct(id, username, name) from user 
where usertype = 2 
AND id in (select id from user where usertype = 3)
```

However that is assuming that ID isn't your PK, that your PK is a combination of id & usertype

A bit more info using an example table and what you expect to get from your query based on the data would clarify the ask

Answer (score 0):

I was over thinking this too much. The credit really goes to Gordon Linoff, he said `or` but I was blinded so I couldn't comprehend.

Here is the solution:

```
$users = User::model()->findAllBySql("SELECT * FROM user WHERE (usertype = 3 or usertype = 1)");
```

---

It was not working before because there is no user who is usertype 1 and usertype 3. It is either one `or` the other.

Comment: in that case "select * from user where usertype in (1,3)" would also work. You need to re-edit your Q as its still asking for 1 AND 3

Answer (score 0):

The query at the end of this should get what you are looking for. The rest sets up the example.

```
drop schema example;

create schema example;

use example;

create table user(
    user_id int primary key,
    name varchar(64)
);

create table type(
    type_id int primary key,
    type_name varchar(64)
);

create table user_type (
    user_id int,
    type_id int,
    foreign key(user_id) references user(user_id),
    foreign key(type_id) references type(type_id)
);

insert into user values (1, 'John');
insert into user values (2, 'Paul');
insert into user values (3, 'George');
insert into user values (4, 'Ringo');

insert into type values (10, 'Guitar');
insert into type values (20, 'Bass');
insert into type values (30, 'Drums');
insert into type values (40, 'Vocals');
insert into type values (50, 'Sitar');

insert into user_type values (1, 10);
insert into user_type values (1, 40);
insert into user_type values (2, 20);
insert into user_type values (2, 40);
insert into user_type values (3, 10);
insert into user_type values (3, 40);
insert into user_type values (3, 50);
insert into user_type values (4, 30);
insert into user_type values (4, 40);

select
    u.*
from
    user u
    join user_type guitar on u.user_id = guitar.user_id and guitar.type_id = 10
    join user_type sitar on u.user_id = sitar.user_id and sitar.type_id = 50
;
```

EDIT: This was done in MySql.  The result set from this query is a single record: George is the only user that matches both types for guitar and sitar.